# When should I use "is" and when "was"?

Tags: tense

I have worked in 3 companies, and I want to tell my friend about my first company.

Should I say "My first company *is* abcd." or "My first company *was* abcd."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Is* refers to something that is happening *now*.  It is present tense.

> The president of the United States *is* Barack Obama.
>
> Dinner *is* served.
>
> The name of the company I'm currently working at *is* A.

All of these things are true right now, so you use *is*.  Barack Obama is still the president, dinner is being served right now, and you are still working for company A.

*Was* refers to things that happened at some point *before* now; this is past tense.

> The president of the United States *was* George Bush.
>
> Dinner *was* delicious!
>
> The first company I worked for *was* A.

All of these things happened in the past.  There was a time when George Bush was president, but now is not that time.  When I ate dinner in the past, I thought it was delicious.  Some time ago I worked for company A, and that was the first company I worked for.  Therefore I use *was*, not *is*.

Comment: @user1114 No problem! Do you understand now, or is there still confusion that I could help explain?

Comment: I understood ,can you explain these sentences ,"He was the man who did that first.","He is the man who did that first.",I think all truths and facts are always in Present tense.

Comment: Me and my friend stand in front of my first company,
What i have to say 
"This was my first company."
I  bought my 3rd phone ,my last two phones are not working ,but they are still with me ,
what i have to say 
"This was my first phone",
"This was my second phone ",
"This is my third phone".

Comment: But, "I have a list of three companies that I've worked for.  My first company is abcd. The second is xyzt."  Is perfectly fine.  The subtlety is in what you are presenting- an item currently in a list, or a company that you worked for in the past.

Comment: @Jim I see the point you're trying to make, but I would never say "My first company is abcd."  "The first company on my list is abcd," sure. *Then* you're presenting an item currently in a list, but not otherwise.

Comment: @WendiKidd- you're right, that is the complete sentence, but I think in many cases the '*on my list*' could get elided in speech to result in "*My first company is...*"

Comment: @Jim,WendiKidd  Can you look at my 2nd and 3rd comments.

Comment: @user1114 "He is the man who did that first" would be correct.  Regarding the phones; that's correct, but for the third phone I'd be more likely to say "This is my new phone" or "This is my current phone."

Comment: @WendiKidd: One could say, "Acme is the first company I worked for." The past tense is accomplished with _worked_, but _is_ would be allowable assuming Acme is still a thriving company. One could also get away with, "Acme was the first company I worked for," and that might even be the preferred way to say it – but especially if Acme was now defunct.