# Neil Armstrong is/was the first astronaut that set foot on the moon. - which one?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

Example 1

> Neil Armstrong is the first astronaut that set foot on the moon.

Example 2

> Neil Armstrong was the first astronaut that set foot on the moon.

Example 3

> Neil Armstrong is the first astronaut that have set foot on the moon.

Example 4

> Neil Armstrong was the first astronaut that had set foot on the moon.

Could you explain the differences?

**My understanding:**

Example 1: proper usage when Armstrong was alive.

Example 2: can be used now since he has passed away.

I am not sure about Example 3 and Example 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["He/she is the first to..." vs. "he/she was the first to...".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274281/he-she-is-the-first-to-vs-he-she-was-the-first-to) Also ["He is/was the first man to go into space" vs. "he is/was the first man to have gone into space"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274946/) and ["this is/was the first thing that I noticed/notice": which one is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244653/) and [When should I use "is" and when "was"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/), among others.

Answer (score 1):

Neil Armstrong *was* the first astronaut *to* set foot on the moon.

(Even while he was among the living, his deed being in the past, we tend to use the past tense.)

> Neil Armstrong is the first astronaut that have set foot on the moon.

“That”?  I would suggest “who” when referring to people, or even individualized animals.

But “have” is here is absolutely wrong.  One astronaut *has* done something.  “Have” is plural.

So, Neil Armstrong is the first astronaut who has set foot on the moon.